# Scraping infinite scrolling pages with load more button using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I was trying to get all project titles and creator names by webscraping and most of it is working, but I got a "TimeoutException: Message:" when I was trying to scrape infinite scrolling pages with "load more" button. Please let me know what is wrong and what i need to correct. Thanks

Below is the code currently being used:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/advanced?sort=newest&seed=2695789&page=1/")

button = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'bttn keyboard-focusable bttn-medium bttn-primary theme--create fill-bttn-icon hover-fill-bttn-icon')))
button.click()

names=[]
creators=[] 
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
for a in soup.findAll('div',{'class':'js-react-proj-card grid-col-12 grid-col-6-sm grid-col-4-lg'}):
    name=a.find('div', attrs={'class':'clamp-5 navy-500 mb3 hover-target'})
    creator=a.find('div', attrs={'class':'type-13 flex'})
    names.append(name.h3.text) 
    creators.append(creator.text)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':names,'Creator':creators})
```

Answer (score 1):

You really need not to use the `Beautiful Soup` and `selenium`. Go for `requests` library and its easy to grab it all hassle free.

```
import requests
import json
records = []
for i in range(5):
    req = requests.get('https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/advanced?google_chrome_workaround&woe_id=0&sort=newest&seed=2695910&page='+str(i),
                       headers={'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    if(req.status_code == 200):
        josn2 = req.json()
        projects = josn2.get("projects") 
        for i in range(len(projects)):
            print("Project Name - " + projects[i]['name'],end='          Created By - ')
            print(projects[i]['creator'].get('name'))

        print("----------------")
```

Output:

[image]

you can scroll down to the page as many time loadmore button loads the content put that much count in the for loop you will get all the content.